# How to add to a queue from FileSystemWatcher Onchanged Event and trigger different actions based on which file is changed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to coding (3 days in) and working on a project using FileSystemWatcher.

My current project is monitoring file changes to trigger an action.

I have it working correctly where it is monitoring a folder, with currently a single .txt file in it, and using OnChanged (looking at lastwrite) it triggers the action as expected. This is all fine and works perfectly, so I'm happy that I understand and can implement a basic FSW with an OnChanged event and trigger the appropriate action (go me, this is only after 3 days of learning C#).

However, I am unsure how to scale this up to multiple .txt files in the same folder, with each file triggering it's own specific  action.

Example:
A.txt, B.txt, and C.txt live in the same folder, using FSW whenever the files are changed I want to trigger an action specific to that file - so when OnChanged A.txt would trigger action a , and B.txt would trigger action b.

I imagine I will need to use queue's, possibly with BlockingCollection(?), however I do not understand how I can get the FSW to add to a queue in a way that it identifies WHICH file has been changed and then how to link that to the specific action for that file.

Any ideas how to mix FSW with queueing to trigger a set action?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have added my base code below (showing the FSW and OnChanged with an example action) - apologies if messy as I'm still learning.

```
void Awake()
        {
            /* Filewatcher to monitor changes to files - lastwrite*/
            var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:Path\to\folder");

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;

            watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        }
        private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Writeline("Hello World");

        }
```

Comment: Check the file name in on changed and do accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FileSystemEventArgs which is passed in the OnChanged handler has the following properties you can use to determine specifics of the action.

**ChangeType**  Gets the type of directory event that occurred.

**FullPath** Gets the fully qualified path of the affected file or directory.

**Name** Gets the name of the affected file or directory

With those you will know which file changed.
How you link the file names to actions can be done in any number of ways.
You could create a simple function that links file name to a method, however you would need to compile if you needed to change the file name or action to execute.